# Struggling with Feeds Importer to custom content type

Tags: 7, feeds

I am struggling to get to grips with the Feeds Importer, getting it to create nodes of my custom content type.

I have created the Feed Importer :

```
$feeds_importer = new stdClass();
$feeds_importer->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default feeds_importer disabled initially */
$feeds_importer->api_version = 1;
$feeds_importer->id = 'feed_new_horizons';
$feeds_importer->config = array(
  'name' => 'New Horizons',
  'description' => 'NASA New Horizons News Feed',
  'fetcher' => array(
    'plugin_key' => 'FeedsHTTPFetcher',
    'config' => array(
      'auto_detect_feeds' => FALSE,
      'use_pubsubhubbub' => FALSE,
      'designated_hub' => '',
      'request_timeout' => NULL,
      'auto_scheme' => 'http',
      'accept_invalid_cert' => FALSE,
    ),
  ),
  'parser' => array(
    'plugin_key' => 'FeedsSyndicationParser',
    'config' => array(),
  ),
  'processor' => array(
    'plugin_key' => 'FeedsNodeProcessor',
    'config' => array(
      'expire' => '2592000',
      'author' => '63',
      'authorize' => 1,
      'mappings' => array(
        0 => array(
          'source' => 'title',
          'target' => 'title',
          'unique' => 1,
        ),
        1 => array(
          'source' => 'description',
          'target' => 'body',
          'unique' => FALSE,
        ),
        2 => array(
          'source' => 'url',
          'target' => 'field_feed_source',
          'unique' => FALSE,
        ),
        3 => array(
          'source' => 'author_name',
          'target' => 'field_feed_author',
          'unique' => FALSE,
        ),
      ),
      'update_existing' => '1',
      'update_non_existent' => 'delete',
      'input_format' => 'full_html',
      'skip_hash_check' => 0,
      'bundle' => 'feed_news_item',
    ),
  ),
  'content_type' => 'feed',
  'update' => 0,
  'import_period' => '1800',
  'expire_period' => 3600,
  'import_on_create' => 1,
  'process_in_background' => 0,
);
```

And although it runs and imports the articles, it does not create the nodes as my custom content 'Feed News Item' - it always creates them as the default 'Feed Item'

I don't see (or understand) how the Feed links to the Importer - I can't see an obvious link between the two, so it's possible I have missed something!

Comment: Well, after much playing I have come to the conclusion that the importer ONLY creates content of type Feed Item, and regardless what I set the bundle to, it simply ignores it.  At the moment, I can't get any text to display in the Feed Item, so I'll restore everything back, install the modules again and start again from scratch....

Answer (score 0):

So I gave up with Feeds Importer.
Despite a clean install, I could not get the feed description to go into any other target field other than description.

Despite setting the text format as Full HTML, it defaulted back to Filtered HTML and would not show the image in the feed. I had to edit each node, change the text format and then it would display.

So, I reverted back to the core aggregator and after some head scratching with CSS, got it to do what I wanted..

You can see the initial result at http://bedsastro.org.uk - this will be revised and updated shortly, but at least I got it working!